# Android application Play Video from SD card

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have to play video from SD card one by one but SD card path having some issue which give error like :-

Unable to open content: file:///storage/emulated/0/sachin.mp4

My code :-

VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

```
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();

    File file = null;
    file = new File(SDCardRoot, "sachin.mp4");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Can you post more of the error log? Did you add the permission for reading the external storage to your manifest file?

Comment: Unable to open content: file:///storage/emulated/0sachin.mp4/sachin.mp4
  java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.

Answer (score 0):

Did u give this permission in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @MplusSoft What is the Anroid version ? From Lollipop Google has introduced a new way of giving app permissions. Just goto your App permission from settings and enable storage for your app.

Comment: @code.hesh, it was introduced in Marshmallow, not Lollipop

Comment: Change your above code as follows

File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath + "sachin.mp4";

    File file = null;
    file = new File(SDCardRoot);